# Razor CheckBoxFor() not bound to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` to set the data for the model I'm posting, which works.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing for a CheckBox to set a bool value in my model, but it doesnt work.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.bringYourOwnDevice, new
                {
                    @class = "form-control",
                    @id = "inputBringyourowndevice",
                })

public class RegisterModel
{
    bool bringYourOwnDevice { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: p.s setting `id` will cause the model binder to not be able to set back the value of your property

Comment: @RezaRahmati that is not true, form elements are posted and bound by their `name`, not their `id`.

Comment: Do you surround the checkbox with a form? What does your action method look like?